# wxWidgets - missing wx/setup.h

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, fedora

Hi installed wxWidgets using "yum install wxGTK-devel" (I'm using fedora 20).
I'm trying to compile the following example file:

### test.cpp:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

using this line:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/wx-2.8 pru.cpp
```

But I get that wx/setup.h doesn't exist. I looked for it and didn't found it anywhere.

The problem is that in wx/platform.h there is the following sentence:

```
#include "wx/setup.h"
```

I don't know how this is supposed to work or how can I make it work.
If you know how to solve this or at least a hint I'll apreciate your help.

Answer (score 5):

Follow this from the [wxWidgets documentation](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Installing_and_configuring_under_Ubuntu):

> ### Linking and Compiling
>
> Normally when you include wxWidgets you say "wx/wx.h" however wxwidgets is in the subdirectory of wx-2.8/wx so what we are going to do is create a link to wx-2.8/wx.
>
> ```
> sudo ln -sv wx-2.8/wx wx
> ```
>
> That's all, now your files should compile correctly.
>
> When you compile your files to include the wxWidgets libraries, add this to the end of your gcc command:
>
> ```
> `wx-config --cxxflags` `wx-config --libs`
> ```

For example:

```
g++ your_code.cpp `wx-config --cxxflags` `wx-config --libs`
```

Comment: That works, but I don't know why... There is no resulting `setup.h` file in my `wx` directory, so is it creating/removing one, or something "under-the-hood"?

Answer (score 2):

You must use `wx-config` to get the compilation flags for wxWidgets programs as already mentioned in the other answer. wxGTK-devel package does include it, as well as the `setup.h` file, at least according to this [listing of its contents](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/wxGTK-devel/contents).

Answer (score 0):

There is `setup.h.in` in wxWidgets root directory which is template for `setup.h`. You can copy and rename it to `setup.h`

It appears that setup with yum is different see [this](http://wx-users.wxwidgets.narkive.com/9LHoZ76E/installing-wxwidgets-under-linux-setup-h-is-a-problem) post. There people suggest executing `/usr/bin/wx-config` or `/usr/bin/wx-config --cxxflags`

The documentation for wx-config can be found [here](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Wx-Config)

Comment: actually there is nothing with that name. I tried compiling wxWidgets myself, but I'm having the same issue

Comment: The correct file name of template is setup.h.in, checked wxGTK source archive downloaded from wxWidgets website and it is there..

Comment: You can't simply create an arbitrary `setup.h` and expect it to work with the pre-built version you already have. The `wx-config` part of this answer is correct, but `setup.h.in` one is not.